# KnockBack ViewModel of Backbone.Collection doesn't seem to create kb.CollectionObservable

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, viewmodel

Take the following code:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({
    items: new Backbone.Collection([
        new Backbone.Model({ ID: 1 }),
        new Backbone.Model({ ID: 2 })        
    ])
});

var vm = new kb.ViewModel(model)
```

Based on what the KnockBack API says (ie: http://kmalakoff.github.io/knockback/tutorial_kb_view_model.html), I would expect that 'vm.items' would be a kb.CollectionObservable.

However, when I attempt to attribute sorting and filtering functions to collection using the kb.CollectionObservable functions 'filter' and 'comparator', these functions are undefined.

```
vm.items.filters
= undefined
```

Usually these functions could be specified via the viewModel constructor options but in my case the items will be pulled down as part of a larger relational model (and the child viewModels are being created using factories at present) so I can't do it that way.

I've confirmed that creating a new kb.collectionObservable from scratch reveals these functions, ie:

```
var collection = new kb.collectionObservable(new Backbone.Collection([
    new Backbone.Model({ ID: 1 }),
    new Backbone.Model({ ID: 2 })        
]))

collection.filters
= function()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have tried using vm.items()?

Comment: That returns an array of view models, without access to those functions I mentioned.

Comment: Try: http://kmalakoff.github.io/knockback/tutorial_nested_models.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the end result was that attempting to turn everything into a kb.collectionObservable was the wrong approach. The better solution was to create a secondary ko.computed result, which then implemented all the filtering and sorting that I needed.

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({
    items: new Backbone.Collection([
        new Backbone.Model({ ID: 1 }),
        new Backbone.Model({ ID: 2 })        
    ])
});

var vm = new kb.ViewModel(model);
vm.Sort() = ko.observable("asc");
vm.SortBy() = ko.observable("ID");
vm.Page() = ko.observable(1);
vm.Filters() = ko.observableArray([]);
vm.PageSize() = ko.observable(20);

vm.Filtered = ko.computed(function () {
    var items = vm.items;

    // Sorting
    items = items.sort(function (first, second) {
        var sortby = vm.SortBy();
        if (first[sortby]() == second[sortby]()) return 0;
        if (vm.Sort() == "asc") {
            return first[sortby]() < second[sortby]() ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (vm.Sort() == "desc") {
            return first[sortby]() > second[sortby]() ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    // Filter
    items = ko.utils.arrayFilter(items, function (vm) {
        var filter = true;
        $.each(vm.Filters(), function (i, filtr) {
            var json = JSON.stringify(vm.model().attributes).toLowerCase();
            if (json.indexOf(filtr.toLowerCase()) < 0) filter = false;
        });
        return filter;
    });

    // Paging
    var startIndex = (vm.Page() - 1) * vm.PageSize();
    var endIndex = vm.Page() * vm.PageSize();
    items = items.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

    return items;
});
```

Additional, you may also need to set sorting on the model itself, so that new items get added in the right order:

```
var setModelComparator = function () {
    vm.model().get("items").comparator = function (a, b) {
        var by = vm.Sort() == "asc" ? 1 : -1;
        var field = vm.SortBy();
        if (a.get(field) == 0) return -1 * by;
        if (b.get(field) == 0) return 1 * by;
        if (a.get(field) < b.get(field)) return 1 * by;
        if (a.get(field) > b.get(field)) return -1 * by;
        return 0;
    };
};
```

Perhaps this is just a case of Knockback being a work in progress and not updating the API docs, who knows.

Thanks also to bvoleti who pointed out the use of [Nested Models](http://kmalakoff.github.io/knockback/tutorial_nested_models.html), a very important part of knockbacks arsenal, particularly when teamed up with [Backbone.Relational](http://backbonerelational.org/).